# Chrome browser displaying cached content even after fetching fresh content from server

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, caching, cache-control

The html page looks like this:

```
    Cache-Control:no-store
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Encoding:gzip
    Content-Type:text/html
    Date:Tue, 04 Feb 2014 14:51:46 GMT
    Server:nginx/1.4.4
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked


  <html>
    <head>
        <script type=javascript>

    funciton buttonClick(){
        var box = document.getElementById("box");
        box.val = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="box">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</textarea>
<button onclick="buttonClick">button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

First I click the button...#box.val == "aaaaaaaaa". Then I visit a different page and then click the back button.  #box.val is still "aaaaaaaa" when it should be "bbbbbbbbbbb".

I can see the browser has made a request to the server for fresh html. However, the browser is displaying "aaaaaaaaaaa".

When I inspect the source of the page in the browser it has "bbbbbbbbbbbbbb" but it displays "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa".

My Chrome version is 32.0.1700.102

This doesn't happen in FF or IE.  Is there anything I can do to prevent this problem.

Comment: Did you check previous questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146813/how-to-stop-chrome-from-caching or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173322/google-chrome-does-not-revalidate-etag-on-back-forth ?

Comment: I'm using Cache-Control: no-store and it still happens.

Comment: As per your comment you are using Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache,max-age=0; Did you try Cache-Control: no-store; only?

Comment: Yes, I've tried all different combinations of those three. The problem still happens in each case.

Comment: Please include toy HTML headers in code

Comment: Html headers are added.

Comment: This is not the correct way of displaying header. Please try my code below. And here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: Next time you answer a question, make sure to publish the FULL code.

Comment: Those are the headers added by the server. It is not html.

Comment: Did you try adding it in HTML, like in code below?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML tags are badly formatted (space before tag name). I did edit your post but also found other javascript detail issues corrected in below code.

Please try out with well formatted HTML. And let us know the outcome.

```
    <html>
        <head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-STORE">
            <script type="text/javascript">

        funciton buttonClick(){
            var box = document.getElementById("box");
            box.val = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <textarea id="box">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</textarea>
    <button onclick="buttonClick();">button</button>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Ok my code was a bit sloppy but it is just to illustrate the problem, its not the actual code i`m using.  But when you run the code you have posted above, can you recreate the problem I`ve described?

Comment: Did you test above code, with HTML header inside HTML code?

Comment: Yes i tried it and it didn't solve the problem.  Can you recreate the issue?

Comment: I think this issue is specific to textareas.  If you change the <textarea> to a <div> the issue goes away.